# How do I convert a SQL date to String date in different format?

Tags: java, sql, string, date, datetime

I have a SQL query result that is returning a date in this format ("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"). My requirement is to convert it to a string (MM/yyyy) and put it in a Map for further comparisons. How Do I proceed to do that. So far this is what I have

```
  Map<String, String> postingDateAmountMap = new HashMap<>();
              postingDateAmountMap.put(rs.getString(3), rs.getString(2));
```

`rs.getString(2)` is returning date as    2021-03-01 00:00:00 whereas I need it as 03/2021 in the map.

NOTE: `getString(3)` and `getString(2)` are the ColumnIndex

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
Map< String , YearMonth > map = … ;
map.put( 
    rs.getString( 3 ) ,  // key
    YearMonth.from( 
        myResultSet.getObject( 2 , LocalDateTime.class )
    )                    // value
);
```

## Use objects, not text

Retrieve smart objects from your database rather than dumb text.

### `LocalDateTime`

If your column is of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, use `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

Be aware that these types do *not* represent a moment as they purposely lack the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

### JDBC 4.2

JDBC 4.2 and later requires a JDBC driver to support the `LocalDateTime` type.

Call the `ResultSet#getObject` method rather than `getString`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

### `YearMonth`

Change your map to a key of `String` and a value of `YearMonth`. The `YearMonth` class represents, well, a year and a month. No day-of-month. Just what you are aiming for in your Question.

```
Map< String , YearMonth > map = new HashMap<>();
String k = rs.getString(3) ; // Named `k` for key of map entry.
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ; 
YearMonth v = YearMonth.from( ldt ) ;  // Named `v` for value of map entry.
map.put( k , v );
```

## Generating text

Later, when you want to present that `YearMonth` to the user as text in format of MM/YYYY, use `DateTimeFormatter` to generate text.

```java
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/uuuu" ) ;
String output = myYearMonth.format( f ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

hi RishiAutomation you can do it by the method split in one line as follow

```
postingDateAmountMap.put(rs.getString(3), rs.getString(2).split("-")[1] + "/" + rs.getString(2).split("-")[0]);
```

or in two lines as follow

```
String[] newDate = rs.getString(2).split("-");
postingDateAmountMap.put(rs.getString(3), newDate[1] + "/" + newDate[0]);
```

Comment: The database likely has date-time types. Java has excellent date-time classes in *java.time*. There is no need for string manipulations.